# Qt Creator's autocomplete (intellisense) doesn't work for std::vector elements

Tags: c++, autocomplete, stl, qt-creator

How can I make autocomplete in Qt Creator work for `std::vector`? Is it normal for it not to work?

For example, on a fresh new project, I create a `struct foo { int bar; };`. If I create a QVector of foo, intellisense/autocomplete works fine:

[image]

But for an `std::vector<foo> v2` **nothing happens** after I press the dot in `v2[0].`

I'm on Qt Creator 3.3.0, using the Visual Studio compiler tool-chain (so the STL comes from VS, not gcc if that makes any difference).

**Edit:** I've found a related bug reported (about iterators though) - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1892. I reproduce this problem as well.

**Edit 2:** I tested with a custom template class:

```
struct bar {
    int b;
};
template<class T> struct foo {
    T operator [](int a) { return T(); }
};
```

And it's working fine:

[image]

Comment: Not possible. Unfortunately, Qt Creator's code model has problems with templates. There was some work going on to make it use clang's, but I don't know how that ended up.

Comment: @cassiorenan Btw, does this reproduce for you as well?

Comment: yes, it does. I'm Using Qt Creator 3.3.2
BTW, your test is flawed. Try implementing an operator[] that simply returns a.

Comment: @cassiorenan Thanks, I fixed the test (it's still working).

Comment: Yes, I tested here as well, after commenting. Apparently std::vector's implementation is the culprit here. Check answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my comments, it's simply not possible to do this. You can file a bug report and hope they get it fixed.
To explain better, it has something to do with std::vector's implementation:

```
reference operator[](difference_type _Off) const
    {   // subscript
    return (*(*this + _Off));
    }
```

In which `reference` is typedef'ed as `Allocator::reference`. Apparently Qt Creator has problems following this to the original class.
Compare that with QVector's...

```
inline T &QVector<T>::operator[](int i)
{ Q_ASSERT_X(i >= 0 && i < d->size, "QVector<T>::operator[]", "index out of range");
  return data()[i]; }
```

...which is defined directly in terms of T&, and you can see why it works for it.

Update: Looking in [cppreference's page on vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), it seems that, after C++11, reference should be typedef'ed as simply value_type&. I have tried building with `CONFIG += c++11` and it still doesn't work, however.

And another update: Managed to code a minimal test case which doesn't work

```
template<typename T>
class foo{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    T a;
    reference operator[](int){return a;}
};

struct bar{int b;};
```

Answer (score 4):

Now the clang code model is available:

Go to Help-> About Plugins... -> enable ClangCodeModel

Restart Qt Creator. Check that it got activated;
Tools -> C++ -> Code Model

Voila code autocomplete for std:vector.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to simplify @Cassio's example code for reproducing the problem:

```
struct T { int b; };
struct foo{
    typedef T value_type;
    T a;
    value_type operator[](int);
    value_type bar();
};
```

What's interesting is that `a.bar().` works but `a[1].` does not. Also, what is most telling is that if you declare operator[] as `foo::value_type operator[](int);`, auto-complete will work.